How to consolidate data from multiple excel files that are saved in multiple folders in a source path
Looking for a vba macro code that can consolidate data from multiple excel files stored in the following manner.
47 excel files stored in their own folders (Need to select data from a file with *Con in its name) / day. I am looking to consolidate this data for 30 days. There'd be overall 1 million rows (Could be more). A macro that I was using doesn't work anymore and it's password protected. So can't check it's code to make corrections.
All excel files have only one sheet with 17 columns (Column names are same across all files) in total and rows will vary and all excel files have different sheet names.
I've searched most of the VBA sites and the following code I found works if I am able to copy all the excel files into a single source folder. But all the files have their own worksheet names where I am facing trouble with this code.
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim Currentbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer, LRow As Long, wbLRow As Long
Dim Import As Range

'Opens File Dialog to Select Which Files You Want to Consolidate
Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With IndvFiles
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
.ButtonName = ""
.Filters.Clear
.Show
End With

If IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'If no files are selected, Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count 'Loop for selected files
    Set Currentbook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(i))
        With Currentbook.Sheets("AWB*")
            LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row of Import     Sheet
            wbLRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 'Last        Row of Destination Sheet
                Set Import = .Range("A2:R" & LRow)
                Import.Copy
                ws.Range("A" & wbLRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
    Currentbook.Close False
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub


Use Currentbook.Sheets(1) if there is only one sheet.

Using Power Query as a replacement method might be more efficient

47 excel files stored in their own folders Are they all in one folder ?  for 30 days does that mean only 30 of the 47 files ?

Using powerquery, this consolidates all tabs on all files in a specified  directory and its subdirectories
 let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
 #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
 #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
 #"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
 #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
 List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
 #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
 in  #"Expanded Data"

paste into home ... advanced editor ... in powerquery

As you have also tagged powerquery you can try this..
To set this up I placed a Form button onto a sheet which calls the following code (or you can just run the macro from the IDE)
Public Sub Consolidate()

    'Select the top most folder
    Dim fldrTop As String
    fldrTop = SelectFolder()
    If Len(fldrTop) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Make it available in a named Range
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("FolderName").Value = fldrTop

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    'Don't add code here unless you set property "Enable Background Refresh" to False

End Sub

My SelectFolder function just uses the FileDialog box
Public Function SelectFolder(Optional startFolder As String = "") As String
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim fns As String

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    If Len(startFolder) = 0 Then startFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = Rbs(startFolder)

    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    Dim r As Long
    r = fDialog.Show()

    If r <> 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        fns = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set fDialog = Nothing
    SelectFolder = fns
End Function
Public Function Rbs(inputStr As String, Optional endChar As String = "\") As String
'Adds the given endChar to the inputStr string if there isn't one there already
    
    If Len(endChar) > 0 Then
        Rbs = IIf(Right$(inputStr, Len(endChar)) = endChar, inputStr, inputStr & endChar)
    Else
        Rbs = inputStr
    End If

End Function

Note that the named range is on the 1st sheet in my "master" workbook, and is called FolderName. I have another named range to hold the way in which I am going to filter the files, called FilterFile - yours will hold the letters "CON"
I then used Data, Get Data, From Other Sources, Blank Query.
Paste the following into that, replacing everything that is there already.
let
    // Use the named range to get all files under the Top folder
    Source = Folder.Files(GetNamedRange("FolderName")),
    // Named Range contains the text forming part of file name
    #"Filter for required filenames" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Name], GetNamedRange("FilterFile"))),
    #"Add Column for Content as a Table" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filter for required filenames", "ContentAsTable", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Folder Path] & [Name]))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Add Column for Content as a Table",{"ContentAsTable"}),
    #"Expand Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "ContentAsTable", {"Name", "Data", "Item", "Kind", "Hidden"}, {"Name.1", "Data", "Item", "Kind", "Hidden"}),
    #"Filter for just WorkSheets" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expand Content", each ([Kind] = "Sheet")),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filter for just WorkSheets",{"Data"}),
    DynamicColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Other Columns1"{0}[Data]),
    #"Expand the Data column" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Data", DynamicColumnNames, DynamicColumnNames),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Expand the Data column", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    HeaderRow = Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "IsAHeader", each List.IsEmpty(List.Difference(Record.FieldValues(_), HeaderRow))),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([IsAHeader] = false))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

Click Done.
Overtype the name Query1 with "Consolidate" then click Close & Load
Do the same again for this helper query "GetNamedRange"
let
    GetNamedRange = (NamedRange) =>
let
    name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=NamedRange]}[Content],
    value = name{0}[Column1]
in
    value
in GetNamedRange

The Power Query will identify all files in sub-folders of FolderName then filter them for filenames containing the text in FilterFile. It reads the sheet(s) regardless of what it is called, and dynamically works out what the column names are (so if extra columns are added at a later date it should keep working)
Word of caution - as this populates an Excel worksheet be wary of the row maximum (1,048,576 in my version)
